# How to send an ajax request to update event in FullCalender UI, when eventDrop is called?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to use this great UI "[FullCalender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/)" But what I want to do is send an ajax request to update the event data in the database when the user move the event around.

So If a user want to move an event to a different date in the calender then I need to be able to send the request to the database use ajax request.

How can I collect the new information so if the appointment was moved to a new date or a new time how can I obtain the new information so I can pass it along to the server?

More, what method do I use to send the same request if the user changes the time by expanding not by drag/drop event?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        editable: true,

        events: "json-events.php",
        timeFormat: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}',
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',


        eventDrop: function(event, delta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {

            if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
                revertFunc();
            }
            // AJAX call goes here
            $.ajax();

        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the parameters of the function: `delta`, `minuteDelta` and `allDay`. Those tell you how the event was modified in days, minutes and if it was moved to the allday slot. The `event` itself should hold an identifier so that you can identify it in your database.

I made me a helper function `updateEventTimes` which is simply called from `eventDrop` and `eventResize` with an extra boolean parameter.

The function looks roughly like this:

```
/*
 * Sends a request to modify start/end date of an event to the server
 */
function updateEventTimes(drag, event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc)
{
  //console.log(event);
  $.ajax({
    url: "update.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: ({
      id: event.id,
      day: dayDelta,
      min: minuteDelta,
      allday: allDay,
      drag: drag
    }),
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
      if (!data)
      {
        revertFunc();
        return;
      }
      calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
    },
    error: function() {
      revertFunc();
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: first, I want to appologive about a long answer. This was a perfect solution for this problem. Thank you so much

Comment: `event.id` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

*Since I found this topic now, I think information below will be helpful in future.*

You could use `JSON.stringify()` method  to generate JSON as send date.
But, small workaround need in this case: see [Tip on serializing event in fullCalendar with JSON.stringify](https://usingfullcalendar.wordpress.com/2016/04/08/tip-on-serializing-event-in-fullcalendar-with-json-stringify/).

In short, you code should looks like:

```js
/*
 * Sends a request to modify start/end date of an event to the server
 */
function updateEventTimes(drag, event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc)
{
  delete event.source; 

  $.post(
    "update.php",
    event,
    function(result) {
      if (!result) revertFunc();
    }
  )
  .fail(function() {
      revertFunc();
  });
};
```