# Jquery FullCalendar API

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar-3

I try to get use to the FullCalender jquery APi version 3.9. Looks like everything is fine, but I would like to be able to do more. I would like to send ajax request to update the calendar in the database each time an event is dropped somewhere.
I already found a topic about this here: [How to send an ajax request to update event in FullCalender UI, when eventDrop is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238405/how-to-send-an-ajax-request-to-update-event-in-fullcalender-ui-when-eventdrop-i)

But I haven't really been able to understand what is told there. Considering the topic last updates was 4 years ago, I think the APi version isn't the same anymore. So I come ask for some help.

I would like to find witch function is called when a task/event is dropped in order to implement the ajax.

The js file contains a little more than 14000 lines so I'm a little bit lost and obviously I'm not going to put the code here. But you can find the API latest version there: https://fullcalendar.io/download

Thanks for your help, hoping someone knows what I should look closer to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up finding the function that is called on the drop. For those who are searching the same thing; the function called on drop is:

`View.prototype.reportEventDrop = function (eventInstance, eventMutation, el, ev)`